# Inheriting from 'object' breaks __getstate__ & __setstate__?

Tags: python, object, pickle

Setting up a base class to handle keeping track of class instances while still allowing garbage collection. The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12102666/1871362) from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101958/keep-track-of-instances-in-python) is close, but I also need to add to the `instances` list when unpickling from saved instances.

Here is my code:

```
import weakref
import pickle
from pprint import pprint
import copy

class BaseClass(object):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        if 'instances' not in cls.__dict__:
            cls.instances = []
        cls.instances.append(weakref.ref(instance))
        return instance

    def __getstate__(self):
        print "pickling"
        d = self.__dict__
        return d

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        print "unpickling"
        self.__dict__ = state
        if 'instances' not in self.__dict__:
            self.instances = []
        self.__class__.instances.append(weakref.ref(self))
        return self

BaseClass.instances = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = BaseClass()
    b = BaseClass()
    c = BaseClass()

    pprint(BaseClass.instances)

    f = file("test.pkl","wb")
    pickle.dump(c,f)
    f.close()

    f = file("test.pkl","rb")
    d = pickle.load(f)
    f.close()

    pprint(BaseClass.instances)
```

So, the weirdness: "unpickling" never gets printed and the `d` instance doesn't make it to the `instances` list, indicating that `__setstate__` never gets called.

If I replace `d = pickle.load(f)` with `d = copy.copy(pickle.load(f))`, then `d` makes it onto the `instances` list and "pickling" prints twice instead of once.

If I replace `class BaseClass(object):` with `class BaseClass:`, then "pickling" and "unpickling" each print once, as expected, and `d` makes in into the list but `a`,`b`, and `c` don't.

Anyone have a clue whats going on? Seems like explicitly inheriting from `object` breaks the default `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` behaviour.

Comment: [`__setstate__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__) is not called when `__getstate__` returns an object which has a false truth value. Did you check if `d` is the empty dictionary in `__getstate__`?
Also, in `__new__` you are creating a *class* attribute `instances`, while in `__setstate__` it's an instance attribute. I doubt that's what you really want to do.

Comment: @Bakuriu Right on. Adding an attribute to the instance when `__new__` is called fixed the problem.