# Calling a method on all instances of an object

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class vehicles:
    class car:
        def drive():
            pass

car1 = car()
car2 = car()
car3 = car()
```

Is there a way I can call the drive function on all the cars in one call, without naming each explicitly.

Comment: you'd have to [keep track of all the instances you have](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101958/keep-track-of-instances-in-python)

Comment: All at once, do you mean in parallel? Or one after another?

Comment: The posted code has a syntax error.  `car1 = vehicles.car() ` will call the constructor.

Comment: Also drive needs a `self` parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want that, you have to design it into your model - so that, for example, you have a registry of all created cars.

It is not a hard thing to do - I think the most obvious way is to customize the 
`__new__` method in your class to keep that registry, and make the calls:

```
class Base:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        self = super.__new__(*args, **kw)
        if not hasattr(cls, _instances):
            cls._instances = []
        cls._instances.append(self)
        return self

    @classmethod
    def call_all(cls, method_name, *args, **kw):
        results = []
        for instance in cls._instances:
            results.append(getattr(instance, method_name)(*args, **kw))
        return results

    def __del__(self):
        self.__class__._instances.remoce(self)

class vehicles:
    class car(Base):

        def drive():
            pass

car1 = car()
car2 = car()
car3 = car()

car.call_all("drive")
```

Another way, since this is class level things that should be kept
when classes are created, could be dealt with in metaclasses. 
The good: it would be "pure" and you would not have special processing that happens when you instantiate the first object of that class as above.
The bad: classes with different metaclasses are hard to combine - and 
if you have a class hierarchy in which some classes need this behavior, and some not - doing this at class level keeps everything interchangeable.

Actually, note that creating the superclass `Base` is an optional step. If you are only using it in one place in all your project, the logic could very well be inside the `car` class itself (as is in the answer by Narcise, bellow.)

If you don't want to do that, you can use the garbage collector (`gc`) module to find out all instances of your object and call the method on them. I don't think that would be a ice thing to do, as the `gc` itself is an
implementation detail for cPython.

```
import gc

...
for obj in gc.get_referrers(car):
     if not isinstance(obj, car): continue
     obj.drive()
```

or in an ugly oneliner:

```
[getattr(obj, "drive")() for obj in gc.get_referrers(car) if isinstance(obj, car)]
```

Comment: Why customize `__new__` and instead of `__init__`?

Comment: It could be done with `__init__` I guess - but since this will fiddle with class attributes only, and the derirved class might want to use `__init__` for other intents, I think it gets better separation. It is more a feeling than a "you should do that" thing.

Comment: Why create a base class, when the `vehicles` class looks as if it's meant to house vehicle types?

Comment: Creating the baseclass is totally optional - and indeeed, I should mention that in the text - but it is a mechanism that will work for any class that inherit from it, and I doubt "car" will be the only place.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Vehicule():

      pos, child = 0, []

      def __init__(self):
          self.__class__.child.append(self)
          self.pos = self.__class__.pos
          self.__class__.pos +=1

      def cond(self):
          print self.pos

      @classmethod
      def drive(cls):
          for v in cls.child:
              v.cond()
```

testing:

```
t = Vehicule()
c = Vehicule()
g = Vehicule()
Vehicule.drive()

>>0
>>1
>>2
```

Comment: nice, simple answer - you can use "@classmethod" instead of "staticmethod" and use cls.child instead of Vehicule.child - that will make it work with sublasses as well, among other benefits.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes there is a way. You can use a [class variable](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) to keep track of instances.

```
class vehicles:

    working_vehicles = [] # this is a class variable

    class car:
        def __init__(self):
            vehicles.working_vehicles.append(self) # adds itself to working_vehicles

        def drive(self):
            pass
```

You can then create instances, and access them from `vehicles.working_vehicles`.

**Demo:**

First create the cars:

```
>>> car1 = vehicles.car()
>>> car2 = vehicles.car()
>>> car3 = vehicles.car()
```

Then access them from `vehicles.working_vehicles`.

```
>>> print(vehicles.working_vehicles)
[<__main__.vehicles.car object at 0x022DF6F0>, <__main__.vehicles.car object at 0x01E97ED0>, <__main__.vehicles.car object at 0x01EAA6B0>]
```

Which isn't really helpful visually, but you can call the `drive` method on *all* the cars, like this:

```
>>> for car in vehicles.working_vehicles:
...     car.drive()
```

Or in one line:

```
>>> map(lambda car: car.drive(), vehicles.working_vehicles)
```

Which won't immediately drive the cars. You would need to call `list` on the `map` iterator.

Comment: Note that `map` returns an iterator in Python 3 that won't immediately drive the cars, as opposed to a `list` in Python 2 that will drive immediately.