# Concatenating multiple pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large number of DataFrames with similar prefix `df_`, that look like:

```
df_1
df_x
df_ab
.
.
.
df_1a
df_2b
```

Of course I can do `final_df = pd.concat([df_1, df_x, df_ab, ... df_1a, df_2b], axis = 1)`

The issue is that although the prefix `df_` will always be there, the rest of the dataframes' names keep changing and do not have any pattern. So, I have to constantly update the list of dataframes in `pd.concat` to create the 'final_df`, which is cumbersome.

**Question**: is there anyway to tell python to concatenate all defined dataframes in the namespace (only) starting with `df_` and create the `final_df` or at least return a list of all such dataframes that I can then manually feed into `pd.concat`?

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101958/how-to-keep-track-of-class-instances can help.

Comment: Why are these similarly structured data frames not contained in a list or dict? Please back up and explain how they are created.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But won't that solution still require me to manually declare each dataframe as an instance of a class?

Comment: If all of the dataframes of interest are in a dict or list, then you simply operate on said dict or list.  You don't need to go searching for dataframes of interest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, using the built-in function [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals):

```
def concat_all(prefix='df_'):
    dfs = [df for name, df in globals().items() if name.startswith(prefix)
           and isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame)]
    return pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Logic:

1. Filter down your global namespace to DataFrames that start with `prefix`
2. Put these in a list (concat doesn't take a generator)
3. Call `concat()` on the first axis.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame([[4, 5], [6, 7]])
other_df = df_1.copy() * 2  # ignore this
s_1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4])  # and this

final_df = concat_all()
final_df

   0  1  0  1
0  0  1  4  5
1  2  3  6  7
```

Always use `globals()` with caution.  It gets you a dictionary of the entire module namespace.

You need `globals()` rather than `locals()` because the dictionary is being used inside a function.  `locals()` would be null here at time of use.