# Find instances of a particular class

Tags: python

Suppose the following code:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

class Student(Person): pass

class Teacher(Person): pass

John = Student('John')
Tom = Student('Tom')
Victor = Teacher('Victor')
```

After the script is run, class `Person` is aware of its subclasses through

```
In [22]: Person.__subclasses__()
Out[22]: [__main__.Student, __main__.Teacher]
```

How to find all instances of class `Student` like:

```
Student.__instances__()
AttributeError: type object 'Student' has no attribute '__instances__'
```

Comment: Create a metaclass that automatically registers instances in `__new__` (preferably decorating any method the user defines). The reason I suggest a metaclass instead of using the parent class is that you will be able to do it on a per-class basis transparently to the user. Alternatively, you could probably use the garbage collector somehow probably. Both options are probably not what you want, the second one with extreme prejudice.

Comment: ty, could please transmit the comment to answer. @MadPhysicist

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/12101958/8033585