# Python: Find Instance of a class by value

Tags: python, oop

i created much instances of a class. Then I want to find one instance by its name. But I get the error message `TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'`.

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def get(self, value):
        if self.value == value:
            return self
        else:
            return None

test_obj = Test('foobar')

print(test_obj.value)

instance = Test.get('foobar')

if instance:
    print(instance.value)
```

Comment: It's a typo. Use `test` instead of `Test`.

Comment: @timgeb Good call, I thought OP meant to call the class but it makes more sense that this is a typo.

Comment: @timgeb No, it's not a typo. I want to find the certain instance.

Comment: ah, ok. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @ikreb I think I understand the intent of your question better now and have updated my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-reading your question again, I think all of us have missed the point so far.  You wanted to check all instances of the class `Test` to see if an instance has the value `'foobar'` (in this case, `test_obj`.  [Referencing this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101958/how-to-keep-track-of-class-instances), you can modify your code like so:

```
class Test(object):
    # class attribute to keep track of class instances
    instances = []
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        Test.instances.append(self)

    # class method to access the get method without any instance
    @classmethod
    def get(cls, value):
        return [inst for inst in cls.instances if inst.value == value]
```

You can then create multiple tests:

```
test1 = Test(1)
test2 = Test(2)
test3 = Test(3)

instance = Test.get(3)
# [<__main__.Test object at 0x03F29CD0>]

instance[0].value
# 3
```

It makes sense for me to return a `list` of instances instead of one single instance.  If you however is only interested in the first match, you can modify the `return` statement accordingly.

---

**Original answer:**

`instance = Test.get('foobar')` is the problem. You're referencing `Test` by its class, not its instance.  So naturally the instance method `.get(self, value)` is looking for the first argument `self` for the instance.

Usually if you already have an instance (e.g. `Test().get('foobar')`) then the instance is passed into the instance method as `self` by default.

You could still call the instance method, but you just need to explicitly pass the instance in:

```
Test.get(test, 'foobar')
```

Answer (score 4):

The `get` method belongs to the instance, not the class. A class *does not know* its instances (you *could* do some dirty tricks to let the class know, but don't). What you need is a list of instances.

One way you could do it

1. override the equality operator
2. create a list of the instances

So, something like

```
class Test:
    def __eq__(self, value):
    return self.value == value

test_list = [Test(5), Test(2), Test(3)]

position = test_list.index(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "get" method of your class is not a class method therefore you have to call it on the instance:

```
test.get("foobar")
```

However if you modify the method to a classmethod than it won't be able to access the instance attributes only the class atributes will be visible.
For a quick solution I think you should store all of the instances in a datastructure (for example in a list) and you can create a function which will loop through the instances and returns the correct one.