# Python getting a class object name based on attribute

Tags: python-3.x, class

How do I get a name of player in seat 3 for example? Thank you!

Note that I do not know that p3 in the one.

```
class Player:
  def __init__(self, name, seat, balance):
    self.name = name
    self.seat = seat
    self.balance = balance

dealer = Player('Dealer', 7, 1000)
p1 = Player('Player1', 1, 100)
p2 = Player('Player2', 2, 100)
p3 = Player('Player3', 3, 100)
p4 = Player('Player4', 4, 100)
p5 = Player('Player5', 5, 100)
p6 = Player('Player6', 6, 100)
```

Comment: You can put them in a list and filter items based on the `.seat` and check their `.name`s.

Comment: With your existing code, there is no Python trick to get what you want, without extra housekeeping. You can make a map of seat to object. That would be one way.

Answer (score 3):

I presume you do not mean to just print the name `p3.name`.

In case you mean to keep track of all the instances of your class, please refer to: [Python: Find Instance of a class by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53449804/python-find-instance-of-a-class-by-value) and [How to keep track of class instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101958/how-to-keep-track-of-class-instances)

If I apply the same logic as mentioned in the two references I have quoted above, your code could look something like this:

```
class Player(object):
    # create a class attribute to keep track of all the instances of the class
    instances = []
    def __init__(self, name, seat, balance):
        self.name = name
        self.seat = seat
        self.balance = balance
        Player.instances.append(self)

    # class method to access player instances by seat
    @classmethod
    def get_players_at_seat(cls, seat):
        return (p for p in cls.instances if p.seat == seat)

dealer = Player('Dealer', 7, 1000)
p1 = Player('Player1', 1, 100)
p2 = Player('Player2', 2, 100)
p3 = Player('Player3', 3, 100)
p4 = Player('Player4', 4, 100)
p5 = Player('Player5', 5, 100)
p6 = Player('Player6', 6, 100)

# Get iterator containing all players at seat 3
players_at_seat_3 = Player.get_players_at_seat(3)

# Print their names
for player in players_at_seat_3:
    print(f"{player.name} is sitting at seat 3")
```

The `get_players_at_seat()` function is a class method that returns an iterator containing all players in `instances` that have their `seat` property set to the given value of `seat`. You can then iterate over the iterator and print the names of the players at seat 3.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to put all your player objects into a list & loop through the list checking their atributes,

```
player_list = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6]

for player in player_list:

    if player.seat == 3:
        print(player.name)
```